# Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved - Same-table reference FK

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I have an SQL database table in which a same-table reference column exist. The column is nullable which means I should be able to add a new record without needing to set a value for that but when I try to save a new record using Linq to SQL in Entity Framework Core, I get the following error:

```
Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved
```

Do I need to make any changes in my EF's database context?